# if statements in python not working

Tags: python

I recently started learning coding. On my first assignment I was asked to make a program that allows the user to choose names and then pick random ones. Here's what I came up with:

```
def main():
  name = ["josh", "omar", "shatil", "cathrin"]
  while True:
    print (name)
    continueProgram = input("would you like to continue")
    if continueProgram.lower() =="yes":
      print(changeList(name))
    else:
      break
def changeList(items):
  changeList= input("Enter 'a' to append list, 'r' to remove an item from the list: ")
  if changeList.lower() == "a":
    appendList = input("what name would you like to add to the list?: ") items.append(appendList)
  if changeList.lower() =="r":
    removeList = input ("what name would you liket to remove from the list?: ")items.remove(removeList)
    return items
main()
```

The last 2 `if` statements aren't working.

Comment: you need to elaborate on what you mean by not working... And do you mean the last two lines?

Comment: @alfasin Huh? `input` strips off the newline itself. Try `print(repr(input('?')))`

Comment: I suspect that stuff got messed up when you posted your code here. `appendList = input("what name would you like to add to the list?: ") items.append(appendList)` raises a SyntaxError because you're trying to put two statements on one line. It's often possible to put multiple statement on one line (by separating them with `;`) but it's not recommended. Please try to make your code nice to read! And that includes putting a blank line at the end of each function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indenting looks suspicious.

Instead of this:

```
def changeList(items):
  changeList= input("Enter 'a' to append list, 'r' to remove an item from the list: ")
  if changeList.lower() == "a":
    appendList = input("what name would you like to add to the list?: ") items.append(appendList)
  if changeList.lower() =="r":
    removeList = input ("what name would you liket to remove from the list?: ")items.remove(removeList)
    return items
```

Try this:

```
def changeList(items):
    changeList= input("Enter 'a' to append list, 'r' to remove an item from the list: ")
    if changeList.lower() == "a":
        appendList = input("what name would you like to add to the list?: ") 
        items.append(appendList)
    if changeList.lower() =="r":
        removeList = input ("what name would you liket to remove from the list?: ")
        items.remove(removeList)
    return items
```

Comment: You might as well drop that `return` statement, since you're mutating the `items` list.

Comment: the only change is that item. append(appendList)  is in a  new line?  new line is ";"  equivalent?